# Python Regex / Regular Expressions - How Do You Get AROUND The Target Text While Leaving Target Text Intact?

Tags: python, json, regex, mongodb

Here is an example of the target text:

*{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7'10\"x10'2\"", "ebay": "{\"_id\": \"6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667\", \"rawColor\": \"Gray\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}", "overstock": "{\"_id\": \"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678\", \"rawColor\": \"Brown/Red\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}"}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7'10\"x10'2\"", "ebay": "{\"_id\": \"6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c\", \"rawColor\": \"Brown/Red\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}", "overstock": "{\"_id\": \"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679\", \"rawColor\": \"Gray\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}"}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7'10\"x10'2\"", "ebay": "{\"_id\": \"6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c\", \"rawColor\": \"Brown/Red\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}", "overstock": "{\"_id\": \"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678\", \"rawColor\": \"Brown/Red\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}"}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7'10\"x10'2\"", "ebay": "{\"_id\": \"6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667\", \"rawColor\": \"Gray\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}", "overstock": "{\"_id\": \"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679\", \"rawColor\": \"Gray\", \"rawSize\": \"7'10\\\"x10'2\\\"\"}"}*

Unfortunately, I need to get this to be accepted by `json.loads` and it's failing because of `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

What I've tried so far is this:

```
import re 
import json

problem = "{'{\"feature1\": \"color\", \"feature2\": \"size\", \"name_color\": \"Gray\", \"name_size\": \"7\\'10\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\"\", \"ebay\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Gray\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\", \"overstock\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Brown/Red\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\"}', '{\"feature1\": \"color\", \"feature2\": \"size\", \"name_color\": \"Gray\", \"name_size\": \"7\\'10\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\"\", \"ebay\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Brown/Red\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\", \"overstock\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Gray\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\"}', '{\"feature1\": \"color\", \"feature2\": \"size\", \"name_color\": \"Gray\", \"name_size\": \"7\\'10\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\"\", \"ebay\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Brown/Red\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\", \"overstock\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Brown/Red\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\"}', '{\"feature1\": \"color\", \"feature2\": \"size\", \"name_color\": \"Gray\", \"name_size\": \"7\\'10\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\"\", \"ebay\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Gray\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\", \"overstock\": \"{\\\\\"_id\\\\\": \\\\\"6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679\\\\\", \\\\\"rawColor\\\\\": \\\\\"Gray\\\\\", \\\\\"rawSize\\\\\": \\\\\"7\\'10\\\\\\\\\\\\\"x10\\'2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\"}\"}'}"
b = problem
b = re.sub(r'\s\\\\"', ' "', b)
b = re.sub(r'\\\\"_id\\\\', '"_id', b) # cleans up area around _id
b = re.sub(r'\\\\":', '":', b) # cleans up post property and colon
b = re.sub(r'\\\\",', '",', b) # cleans up post property and comma
b = re.sub(r'\\\\"}"}', '}}', b) # cleans up ending of string 
b = re.sub(r'\\\\\\\\\\\\"', '\\\\\\"', b) # fixes inches backslashes
b = re.sub(r'\\\\"', '\\"', b) # clears up escaping inches
b = re.sub(r'"",', '",', b) # clears up extra quotation marks
b = re.sub(r'"{"', '{"', b)
finally_b = b[1:-1:] # removes the extra { and } from the ends 
print('b...')
print(b)
print()
print('finally_b...')
print(finally_b)
json.loads( finally_b )
```

Output:

```
b...
{'{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}'}

finally_b...
'{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee72b7f86b42582b466c", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4678", "rawColor": "Brown/Red", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}', '{"feature1": "color", "feature2": "size", "name_color": "Gray", "name_size": "7\'10\"x10\'2\", "ebay": {"_id": "6175ee6eb7f86b42582b4667", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"\"}", "overstock": {"_id": "6175eef7b7f86b42582b4679", "rawColor": "Gray", "rawSize": "7\'10\"x10\'2\"}}'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there a better way to handle things parts like  `\\\\\"rawSize\\\\\"` and turning those into `"rawSize"`?  That is what I mean by a way to go AROUND the word `rawSize` and just clean up what is surrounding that word.

Comment: that looks a bit messy. Could you clean your question and strip it down to its core and provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @mnist ok, done

Comment: What is generating that string?  Can it be modified to output valid JSON?

Comment: "I need to get this to be accepted" no, you tell the provider it isn't JSON and fix their side. This not-JSON string is garbage as it stands, and while you might be able to hack/fudge it to work for JSON loads for this string, what about the next string or the one after that, will your same code work on that?

Answer (score -1):

I think the data looks corrupted to me. Look at this part:
`"name_size": "7'10\"x10'2\""`
The " and ' around the 7 both do not have a backslash. That is just going to be a problem when interpreting.

Personally, I suggesting cleaning up the string. You can convert the string into a raw string, maybe by encoding by `test_string.encode('unicode_escape')`
Then make sure every " and ' has backslash in front of it, then json load it?